# What does the . operator do in matlab?

Tags: matlab, operators, dot-operator

I came across some matlab code that did the following:

```
thing.x=linspace(...
```

I know that usually the `.` operator makes the next operation elementwise, but what does it do **by itself**?  Is this just a sub-object operator, like in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its subobject.

You can have things like
    Roger.lastname = "Poodle";
    Roger.SSID = 111234997;
    Roger.children.boys = {"Jim", "John"};
    Roger.children.girls = {"Lucy"};

And the things to the right of the dots are called fields.

You can also define classes in Matlab, instatiate objects of those classes, and then if `thing` was one of those objects, `thing.x` would be an instance variable in that object.

The matlab documentation is excellent, look up "fields" and "classes" in it.

There are other uses for `.`, `M*N` means multiploy two things, if `M`, `N` are both matrices, this implements the rules for matrix multiplication to get a new matrix as its result.  But `M.*N` means, if M, N are same shape, multiply each element.  And so no like that with more subtleties, but out of scope of what you asked here.

As @marc points out, dot is also used to reference fields and subfields of something matlab calls a struct or structure.  These are a lot like classes, subclasses and enums, seems to me.  The idea is you can have a struct `data` say, and store all the info that goes with data like this:

```
olddata = data; % we assume we have an old struct like the one we are creating, we keep a reference to it

data.date_created=date();
data.x_axis = [1 5 2 9];
data.notes = "This is just a trivial example for stackoverflow.  I didn't check to see if it runs in matlab or not, my bad."
data.versions.current = "this one";
data.versions.previous = olddata;
```

The point is ANY matlab object/datatype/whatever you want to call it, can be referenced by a field in the struct.  The last entry shows that we can even reference another struct in the field of a struct.  The implication of this last bit is we could look at the date of creation of the previous verions:

```
data.versions.previous.date_created
```

To me this looks just like objects in java EXCEPT I haven't put any methods in there.  Matlab does support java objects which to me look a lot like these structs, except some of the fields can reference functions.

Comment: I was under the impression `.*` was the elementwise multiply operator. What's different about `+.*`?

Comment: +.* is an operator only in APL, not in MATLAB.

Comment: @woodchips whoops I learned APL 35 years ago and it still haunts my dreams.  I fixed the "typo" with an edit.

Comment: it's also used to access struct members.

Comment: @Marc I added mention of structs explicitly above to celebrate getting an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it's a form of indexing, as per mwengler's answer. However, it can also be used for method invocation on objects in recent versions of MATLAB, i.e.

```
obj.methodCall;
```

However note that there is some inefficiency in that style - basically, the system has to first work out if you meant indexing into a field, and if not, then call the method. It's more efficient to do

```
methodCall(obj);
```